# Is this a normal way to install a tire?

Tags: quick-release

So I don't have a clue about bicycles. I wanted to replace the tires on my bike but couldn't figure out the size. So I went to a local bike shop where they showed me tires that would fit my bike. They gave me an estimate, I left my bike with them and went on my merry way. I called on the day they said that they would start the work just to make sure that everything was cool. They said that everything was fine and told me it would be finished the next week. When I came to pick it up they increased the cost by adding these implements. They did this to get enough relief on the brake cable so as to install the new over-sized tire. Is it in the bike shop culture to do this kind of thing without fist contacting the customer. Now, in the future when I plan to replace the tire with the original size I am afraid I will need to learn the skill of brake cable installation and need to pay for more parts/cables. Please see the attached photos.

Any help would be much appreciated. Also, I told him that I didn't have a clue about bikes, period.
[image: rear brake]
[image]

Comment: I'd be concerned they spent your money without asking.  How much more did it cost, either in your currency or as a percentage ?

Comment: Just say NO.  If there was an extra price for an over-sized tire that should have been quoted.   A side pull brake does not handle a large tire and any competent mechanic should know that.

Comment: What they did is a bit unusual but probably reasonable.  You do not need to undo the work to put narrow tires on later.  If they didn't charge you a ton for the two new barrel adjusters, I'd say they did OK apart from failing to warn you about the increase in cost.

Answer (score 6):

It's hard to tell exactly what was done and why – it would help to know the original and new tire sizes. But what it looks like is that the shop added inline barrel adjusters to your brake cables. That's consistent with your description as well. They probably added them because the release levers on the brakes didn't give enough clearance to remove/install the wheels with the new tires without having to undo the cable clamp bolts. This is to make it easy for you to repair flats and the like.

I would have expected the shop to contact you and tell you that the new tires were too wide to work with your current brakes and offer you options for the solution. One solution would have been to use a narrower tire, another is adding the barrel adjusters.

Comment: I have a third solution that I use with 28mm tires on narrow rims with sidepull brakes.  I release some tension with the brake QR, then more with the brake barrel adjuster if possible, and if it's still not enough, I push the brake cable housing out of place in the frame stop/guide.  It helps if the brake cable is adjusted such that the barrel adjuster is normally screwed out a bit.

Comment: Also, some brake levers have a means of gaining some extra slack as well. Changing levers would almost certainly cost more than adding the inline barrel adjusters, but choosing levers with this function (e.g., [Tektro RL340](http://www.tektro.com/_english/01_products/01_prodetail.php?pid=67&sortname=Lever&sort=1&fid=3)) would be an option if you are building up a bike and knew that you wanted to be able to run wide tires.

Comment: Let air out of the tire and pinch the tire to get it past the pads. Don't inflate tire prior to installation.

Answer (score 1):

The long black bit looks like a really big barrel adjuster to me.
(edit not an in-line brake booster/multiplier as I originally guessed)

Do you know what the original size tyre was, and what the new one is ?

If you're replacing a tyre with the same width of tyre then the brakes should not need significant changes, perhaps a small adjustment for brake wear over time.

If the new tyres are bigger or have a knobblier profile, then its possible they may may be rubbing on the brakes.  The brake pads may be let out to allow room, but now won't close up enough before the brake lever bottoms on your handlebar, leading to poor braking.

You'll be fine to fit the original size of tyre without further change.

Comment: What the hell is a "brake booster/multiplier"?

Comment: @MikeBaranczak Certainly not what is in that picture.

Comment: @MikeBaranczak  Looks like I confused two separate and different things.
Brake boosters are actually horseshoe-shaped frames to stiffen the bosses on a cantilever brake eg  http://www.chainreactioncycles.com/nz/en/brand-x-thermoplastic-v-brake-booster/rp-prod8215
The image made me think of inline brake power modulators for V brakes, that look like this http://forums.mtbr.com/brake-time/shimano-power-modulator-v-brakes-349988.html  
Sorry for the misleading bits in my answer (edited now)